# Visual Studio 2010 - intellisense in comments

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Is it possible to create an intellisense-like link to a class / class property / class method in a simple comment in Visual Studio 2010 (doing ASP.NET MVC 3 project but i guess that doesn't really matter)? Are there any free plugins for this functionality?

Let's say I have this code:

```
//Blahblahblah
//As you can see on its definition - [SomeClass.SomeProperty] - blahblahblah
//blahblahblah
SomeInstanceOfSomeClass.CallingSomethingUsingSomeProperty(42);
```

I want to click on [TableModelClass] which will either open new tab or switch to already opened one and scroll automatically to the definition of class/method/etc., as if you typed F12 on it anywhere else outside comments.

I suspect there must be some VS plugins out there in the Internet...been googling for a while...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add a link to another type.method that will actually appear as a clickable link in your code.

However, you can use [XML documentation comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx) to add a link to another type/method that will appear as a clickable link in the Object Browser, in the generated XML documentation file, or in any other documentation that you might generate from these comments using tools like [Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/).

The syntax is to use either the [`<see>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acd0tfbe.aspx) or [`<seealso>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhd7ehkk.aspx) tag, and specify the type/method you want to link to as the [`cref` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc837134.aspx).

For example:

```cs
/// <summary>This is a helper method to add two integer values together.
/// <para>
/// <see cref="System.Console.WriteLine(System.Int32)"/> for information
/// about how to display the results.
/// </para>
/// <seealso cref="MyClass.Subtract"/>
/// </summary>
public static int AddIntegers(int a, int b)
{
    return (a + b);
}
```

Comment: Isn't there any plugin for this functionality? Being able to link any method in any comment anywhere in the code sounds like a very useful ability to me

Comment: @Motig: Really? I can't imagine ever using it. What would happen when you clicked on the hyperlink? It would take you to the method information in the Object Browser? To the method definition?

Comment: Method definition, yes. It would open the tab with the file where the method is defined - the same functionality as if you right clicked the method call and choosed "Go to definition". I wouldn't even mind if the plugin worked by its own syntax (any string in comments surrounded by two hashes (or something like that) would make that string Intellisense-clickable)

Comment: @Motig: I'm not aware of any extension or add-in that does this. But VS 2010 is pretty extensible... :-) The only thing this reminds me of is [Noah Richards's excellent Go To Definition extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4b286b9c-4dd5-416b-b143-e31d36dc622b). I use this all the time, but I've never wanted to create hard links in my source code.

Comment: Oh, I've been looking for ctrl+click aswell, thanks for that x)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but in Visual Studio 2008/2010 you can use the built-in intellisense by simply using triple slashes `///`. Ie:

```
/// <summary>
/// My method summary
/// </summary>
/// <param name="myParam">some text</param>
void MyFunction(int myParam)
{}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for the ability to make a link to any class anywhere in the code, not just in the property/method definition. And I don't see how can be anything after triple slashes linked to a particular definition.